# Subject.next() not making it to observers

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have created a mechanism for other services to register themselves with the main communication service. This is so that the communication service can dispatch messages either to a target service or to a target component. In this mechanism I allow an id to be passed in

```
public register(id : number) : Subject<HMessage>{
  console.log("creating new subject named "+id);
  let subject = Subject.create();
  this.addToMap(subject,id);

  return subject;
}
```

The id is just based on an enum.

```
export enum MessageType{
  AuthMessage,
  DefMessage,
  DeltaMessage,
  KeepAliveMessage,
  ServerLog,
}
```

Here I am just leveraging a map that I initialize in the `NgInit` of the communication service.

```
this.map = new Map<number,Subject<HMessage>>();
```

It is stored there for retrieval later when I process an incoming message to be dispatched.

```
private processIncoming(message : HMessage){
  console.log("Incoming>>>",message.type,message.data);
  let subject = this.map.get(message.type);
  if(subject){subject.next(message);}
  else{console.log(message.type+" doesn't have a target subject available to receive the message!")}
}
```

I have several console logs in different places to see where it is and is not getting to. The example incoming message is for a server log which is subscribe to the registered subject here:

```
this.register(MessageType.ServerLog).subscribe({ next: (message) => this.toConsole(message.data)});
```

The method just outputs the data of the message which in this case is just a string to the console.

Based on the console logs the return message is coming through fine. It is hitting the `processIncomingMessage` so everything before that is working fine helps the specific code here.

Somethings I noted in debugging:

1) I am only adding 1 subject to my map.
2) I can get the subject from the map and I can call next on it. 
3) The specific next function for the subscription noted is not coming through for some reason.

The last point, I am at a loss as to why this is not coming through. No errors so the subject is created and next is being called but the function never gets executed as I would expect.

**EDIT - I also see from debugging that the `observers` array on the Subject is empty. So when I subscribe I would expect that array to have at least 1 element in it. Based on my assumptions, I suspect that the subscribe is not working and therefore it does perform the next operation but with no subscribers in the array it doesn't go anywhere. Not sure why the subscribe is not adding an observer when I pass an anonymous object with a `next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Subject.create()` expects 2 arguments an observer and an observable ([docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md#rxsubjectcreateobserver-observable)). I've never actually used Subject.create(), but I assume its to build out your own custom implementation of a Subject if the predefined Subjects don't fit your needs. In your case I believe the basic Subject will work. So you can change

```
public register(id : number) : Subject<HMessage>{
    let subject = Subject.create();
    this.addToMap(subject,id);

    return subject;
}
```

to

```
public register(id : number) : Subject<HMessage>{
    let subject = new Subject(); // change to basic subject
    this.addToMap(subject,id);

    return subject;
}
```

Comment: That's the answer...grrrrrrr